# NSURLSession - Garbage Data At End (WatchOS)

Tags: nsurlsession, swift2, watchos-2

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me understand an issue I am facing when trying to implement a NSURLSession in my WatchOS 2 application.

For whatever reason, I receive the error;

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end."
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

but **only** after I've run my app once.  The first time I run the WatchOS app in the Simulator, the data I am downloading is received and parsed without issue.  The second+ time I run the app, I receive the aforementioned error.

I have run my JSON through every possible validator I can find, and it validates with no problem.  The data seems to work, but only on the first launch.  If I watch a period of time (10+ minutes it seems), then run the app in the Simulator again, it works once, then I receive the error.

Here is my truncated code from the **InterfaceController.swift** file;

```
func getData() {

    let myURL = "http://www.myurl.com/sample.json"

    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

    let conf = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: conf)

    dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(dataURL!) { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil, let data = data else {
        return
        }

        do {

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray  

            for item in json {
                let name: String? = item["name"] as? String
                let email: String? = item["email"] as? String
                let nickName: String? = item["nickName"] as? String

                let file = Data(
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    nickName: nickName)

                self.files.append(file)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.reloadTable()
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    dataTask!.resume()
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a temporary fix. Set:

```
sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
```

Looks like this is caused by a bug in the request cache.

Comment: This has resolved my issue.  Thank you!  For anyone interested, I had to use `sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData` in my code.  This issue only _seems_ to occur when run in the Simulator, and not on the device itself.  The pattern I've been able to discern is that the issue occurs when the data being gathered is identical to the last set of data that was gathered; if your data changes between builds, the issue does not seem to occur.

Comment: did you file a bug with Apple?

Comment: Life saver. Thank you.